# Question with balls!

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

If I need to split 4 white identical balls and 1 green, 1 red and 1 blue balls (7 in total) to 5 different cells, when cells can be empty and you can put as much balls as you wish in each cell, with the exception that in each cell there can be a maximum of 1 white ball, how many options have I got?

Thanks

Comment: by the way my answer is 625, I don't know if it's correct though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $5$ choices for which cell the white ball isn't in.  Each other ball has $5$ possibilities, so a total of $5 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5 = 625$